# Join table Quantity with cocoon (has_many through)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, join, cocoon-gem

I didn't find anything related to my problem.
I have these models:

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meal_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :meal_ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meal_ingredients
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meal_ingredients
  has_many :meals, through: :meal_ingredients
end

class MealIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meal
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

In the meal_ingredient model I have a **quantity** column and I want to let the user set this quantity when creating a new meal with many ingredients. To allow that, I used the **cocoon** gem. And that's when the problem comes: I must set the `ingredient_id` and the `meal_id` to build the association with the quantity but I just hit the database when submiting the "Create Meal" buttom.
Part of the solution I thought is creating a `fields_for`inside the form and set an instance variable in the controller.
But how can I get these ids? I'm stuck.

```
class MealsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_meal, only: [:edit, :update, :show]
  autocomplete :ingredients, :name

  def index
    @meals = Meal.order(updated_at: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @meal = Meal.new
    @qtd = MealIngredient.new
  end

  def create
    @meal = Meal.new(meal_params)
    @qtd = @meal.ingredients.map{|r| MealIngredient.new(quantity: params[:quantity], ingredient_id: r.id, meal_id: @meal)}
    if @meal.save
      flash[:success] = "Refeição criada com sucesso!"
      redirect_to meals_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @meal.update(meal_params)
      flash[:success] = "Your meal was updated succesfully!"
      redirect_to meal_path(@meal)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

    def meal_params
      params.require(:meal).permit(:name, :picture, ingredients_attributes: [:name, :unit, :carb, :prot, :fat])
    end


    def set_meal
      @meal = Meal.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

This is what I got so far... I don't think the main problem is being caused by cocoon gem. I think it's about concepts...

The params

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dTYOiz8+pwNfwt432qhy7Yuj0hSVksj0bsTzxp8vD6QaupIJueSO1ASDkwiOB92qCiLO33Ke61aUBGbyvGZJfA==", "meal"=>{"name"=>"tests", "ingredients_attributes"=>{"1449471543091"=>{"name"=>"uva", "unit"=>"und", "carb"=>"1", "prot"=>"1", "fat"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "meal_ingredient"=>{"quantity"=>"14"}, "commit"=>"Create Meal"}
```

View
**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class = "row">
  <div class= "col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <%= simple_form_for(@meal) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :name %>
      </div>
      <h3>ingredientes</h3>
      <div id="ingredients">
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient| %>
          <%= render "ingredient_fields", :f => ingredient %>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-actions">
        <div><%= link_to_add_association 'adicionar ingrediente', f, :ingredients, :class => "btn btn-default" %></div>

        <div><%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-success" %></div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_ingredient_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', obj: @meal %>
<div class = "nested-fields">
  <table class= "table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= f.label "Nome" %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.label "Unidade" %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.label "Carbo" %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.label "Prot" %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.label "Gordura" %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.label "Quantidade" %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.label "kcal" %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td scope="row" class="col-md-4">
            <%= f.text_field :name, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-2">
            <%= f.text_field :unit, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= f.text_field :carb, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control" %>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= f.text_field :prot, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control" %>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= f.text_field :fat, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control" %>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= fields_for @qtd do |f| %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :ingredient_id %>
              <%= f.number_field :quantity, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control" %>
            <% end %>
          </td>          
          <td class="col-md-1">
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= link_to_remove_association "remove item", f, :class => "btn btn-danger" %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this tutorial](https://hackhands.com/building-has_many-model-relationship-form-cocoon/) and looking at the [cocoon's demo](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo) app. It was easy to solve my problem, although I actually don't know exactly what I did here the 
`<%= link_to_add_association 'adicionar ingrediente', f, :meal_ingredients, 'data-association-insertion-node' => "#ingredients ol", 'data-association-insertion-method' => "append", :wrap_object => Proc.new {|quantity| quantity.build_ingredient; quantity }, :class => "btn btn-default" %>`
I hate coding this way but this time I just went with the flow very carefully...
***If someone has already used cocoon for that purpose and can explain better I - and the community - would appreciate :D***
Changes made:
**Model**

```
class MealIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meal
  belongs_to :ingredient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient, :reject_if => :all_blank
end
```

**Controller**

```
class MealsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_meal, only: [:edit, :update, :show]
  autocomplete :ingredients, :name

  def index
    @meals = Meal.order(updated_at: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @meal = Meal.new
  end

  def create
    @meal = Meal.new(meal_params)
    if @meal.save
      flash[:success] = "Refeição criada com sucesso!"
      redirect_to meals_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @meal.update(meal_params)
      flash[:success] = "Your meal was updated succesfully!"
      redirect_to meal_path(@meal)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

    def meal_params
      params.require(:meal).permit(:name, :picture, :tcarb, :tprot, :tfat, :tkcal, meal_ingredients_attributes: [:quantity, ingredient_attributes: [:id, :name, :unit, :carb, :prot, :fat, :_destroy]])
    end


    def set_meal
      @meal = Meal.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

**Views**
**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class = "row">
  <div class= "col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <%= simple_form_for(@meal) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :name %>
      </div>
      <h3>ingredientes</h3>
      <fieldset id="ingredients">
        <ol>
          <%= f.fields_for :meal_ingredients do |meal_ingredient| %>
            <%= render "meal_ingredient_fields", :f => meal_ingredient  %>
          <% end %>
        </ol>

        <div class="form-actions">
          <div><%= link_to_add_association 'adicionar ingrediente', f, :meal_ingredients, 'data-association-insertion-node' => "#ingredients ol", 'data-association-insertion-method' => "append", :wrap_object => Proc.new {|quantity| quantity.build_ingredient; quantity }, :class => "btn btn-default" %></div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-actions">
        <div><%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-success" %></div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_meal_ingredient_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class = "nested-fields">
  <table class= "table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= f.label "Nome" %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.label "Unidade" %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.label "Carbo" %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.label "Prot" %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.label "Gordura" %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.label "Quantidade" %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.label "kcal" %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <%= f.fields_for :ingredient do |fi| %>
          <td scope="row" class="col-md-4">
            <%= fi.text_field :name, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-2">
            <%= fi.text_field :unit, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= fi.text_field :carb, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control" %>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= fi.text_field :prot, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control" %>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= fi.text_field :fat, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control" %>
          </td>
          <% end %>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= f.number_field :quantity, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control" %>

          </td>          
          <td class="col-md-1">
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= link_to_remove_association "remove item", f, :class => "btn btn-danger" %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used cocoon also, and had some troubles setting it up. I think you have to realiaze that Rails is smarter then you think. You can easily just call save on the parameter string. Just make sure the parameters are all accepted. You will also need :id for ingredients_attributes for instance (and :_destroy, if you allow deletion as well). Oh, and loose the nested_attributes for your join table as well.

I think something like this should work:

```
  def new
    @meal = Meal.new
  end

  def create
    @meal = Meal.new(meal_params)
    if @meal.save
      flash[:success] = "Refeição criada com sucesso!"
      redirect_to meals_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
private

    def meal_params
      params.require(:meal).permit(:name, :picture, ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name, :unit, :carb, :prot, :fat, :_destroy])
    end
```

If it doensn't, please post your views that contain the main form and the partials.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The way you suggested, seems there are no params for the join table. Everything is working, but nothing is collecting the 'quantity' param. I thought about doing another nested form inside the actual form.
Btw, I've added my view form. :)